# Segmentation fault when reading file in C

Tags: file, segmentation-fault, scanf

I'm trying to read from a file. My program reads the first line correctly, but at the second line I get a segmentation fault and I have no idea why that is.

Here's my code (sorry it's in Hungarian) :

```
FILE *fp = fopen (fajlnev, "r");
if (fp == NULL) {
    perror("Fájl megnyitása sikertelen");
    return;
}
char tmp [21];
strcpy(tmp,nev);
strcpy(pj->nev,"\0");
char buf1, buf2, buf3;
fscanf(fp, "%c%c%c", &buf1, &buf2, &buf3);
while (strcmp(pj->nev, tmp)!=0 ) {
    fscanf(fp, "%s %d %d\n", pj->nev, &(pj->meret), &(pj->pontszam));       

    for(int i=0; i<pj->meret; i++) {
        for(int k=0; k<pj->meret; k++) {
            fscanf(fp, "%u",  &(pj->foldek[i][k].n));
            fscanf(fp, "%d", &(pj->foldek[i][k].allapot));
            fscanf(fp, "%ld", (long *)&(pj->foldek[i][k].ido));
            printf("hiba");

        }
    }
 fscanf(fp, "\n");
}
```

`pj->foldek[i][j].n` is an enumerated type, `allapot` is an integer and `ido` is `time_t`

I'd be really grateful if you could help me! :)

Comment: Hi Petra, you are not using any debugger obviously, but there's something easy to do. Try to replace the two strcpy calls strcpy(tmp,nev);
strcpy(pj->nev,"\0"); with memcpy or with strncpy calls and see if you can fix it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Please alter the while loop:
while (!feof(fp) && strcmp(pj->nev, tmp)!=0 )